# EWS returns "Custom Time Zone" - how to store it in SQL?

Tags: c#, timezone, exchangewebservices

When using the EWS `GetUserAvailability()` function, I get in the `AttendeesAvailability[i]` object a [`WorkingHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.workinghours%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) object containing a Start, an End, the WeekDays, and a `TimeZoneInfo` object.

For me, the `TimeZoneInfo` object always has the name `Custom Timezone` and a GUID as ID, so I cannot restore the very same time zone using `FindSystemTimeZoneById`.

The time zone that the user can select for his availability, however, is one of the system time zones, so I really expected to find a system time zone returned here. How can I find - from EWS - which system time zone the user has selected in his Outlook or OWA account settings?

If I can't, what is the appropriate way to store a `TimeZoneInfo` object in SQL server?

Comment: I'm very interested in this.  Could you provide some examples?  Please give an example value of what is set in OWA, and what you get back from `TimeZoneInfo.ToSerializedString()`.  An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found out that the problem is the EWS XML format. As can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/aa563496(v=exchg.150).aspx), it does not contain the full time zone information (e.g. name), only a subset:

```
  <TimeZone>
    <Bias>480</Bias>
    <StandardTime>
      <Bias>0</Bias>
      <Time>02:00:00</Time>
      <DayOrder>5</DayOrder>
      <Month>10</Month>
      <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
    </StandardTime>
    <DaylightTime>
      <Bias>-60</Bias>
      <Time>02:00:00</Time>
      <DayOrder>1</DayOrder>
      <Month>4</Month>
      <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
    </DaylightTime>
  </TimeZone>
```

This subset is then parsed back into a time zone [in this EWS Managed API code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Misc/Availability/LegacyAvailabilityTimeZone.cs), with this really useful Guid "Id" (the Id is different every time I call `GetUserAvailability`, although the timezone is still the same):

```
return TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    -this.bias,
    "Custom time zone",
    "Standard time",
    "Daylight time",
    new TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[] { adjustmentRule });
```

So I guess I can expect that in 99% of the cases I will find one or more matching time zones in the list of available system time zones, and I am for now using the extension method:

```
public static TimeZoneInfo ToSystemTimeZone(this TimeZoneInfo customTimeZone)
{
    var tz = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasSameRules(customTimeZone));
    if (tz != null) return tz;
    else return customTimeZone;
}
```

This provides the first system time zone that has the same rules as the custom time zone. It's not a 100% match, since there may be multiple time zones with the same rules, but at least this should keep all the time zone information that is exposed via EWS.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will fail to match in any cases where there is more than one adjustment rule, as it doesn't appear that the entire rule definition is exposed.  You may just want to compare the *current* rule, or the one associated with the calendar event timestamp (if there is one).  The problem then is that you may find multiple different time zones that have the same rule and offset at that point in time, so you'd have no way to disambiguate.

Comment: Really, it seems like this may be an impossible task, given the limited amount of detail returned by EWS.  There's an implied assumption that a single rule is good enough, but really it's not.

Comment: Well, then what did Microsoft think when they defined an API that gives us impossible tasks!?